# Mongoose : query on a field on an array of ref documents,

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

here are my models:

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema(
{
    events: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Event'
        }
    ]
})
var EventSchema = new Schema(
{
    title  : String,

    location: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Location'
    }
})
```

I would like to query from the Location model a field inside the Event model.

The following one doesn't work

```
findOne({events: {$elemMatch: {title: 'test'}}})
```

I'm not sure even that's possible to make it ...

Comment: It's not possible, which is why you use emedding instead.There is a section somewhere in the docs that shows using `.filter()`,

Comment: Thank you guys, I did with the populate, but it's not too greedy to request ALL the documents, and to filter after ?

Comment: Why do you want to query from Location when you're looking for something inside the Event model/collection?

Comment: @robertklep because I have fields in my Location model that I want to select too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use references you can use [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to run a "sub query" on referenced documents to select which ones should be included.

```
Location.find({ ... }).populate({
  path  : 'events',
  match : { title : 'test' }
}).exec(...);
```

Which way around (query `Location` and populate `Event`, or the other way around) depends on the exact query you need to run. It's most performant to run the "main" query on the model that will yield the least results.

This method will still return all documents that matched the main query, and you have to perform some postprocessing to filter the documents that don't have any matched event references.

Comment: How would you query the other way arround (if you have few selection criterion on Location) without writing two queries ?